# Script terminating at "IF /I %Line%==Say goto DoTheSay"

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement

So I have this bit from a script of batch code I'm writing:

```
set /P Line=<Line.txt
set Line=%Line:~6,-1%
echo %Line% > Stripped.txt

:IsLineSay
IF /I %Line%==Say goto DoTheSay
IF /I %Line%==Pause goto DoThePause

set Line=%Line:~0,-1%
goto IsLineSay

:DoTheSay
cls
echo hi
pause
```

(Line.txt contains `100 | Say-`)

Whenever I run it it closes at the `IF /I %Line%==Say goto DoTheSay`
 part. It doesn't give an error message or anything, just quits the batch file.

Why is this happening and any ideas on how to fix it? I have absolutely no idea why this happens. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no error in the code. It runs fine until (including)  the `pause`. What do you *expect*  it to do?

Comment: You will have to show us a larger selection of your batch file.  The code you provided has no problems.

Comment: @Stephan I added more, the rest of my script has basically nothing to do with this part. Line is a new variable added here, all of these are new labels.

Comment: I suspect that your data file is either saved as mac/*nix format (LFs only, not CRLF) or that it's saved as Unicode. Both of these will yield the error of which you complain. It needs to be ANSI with CRLF to be read by this code.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `|` that makes trouble. The parser doesn't treat it like a normal character. It's called a "pipe" and is meant to transfer the output of the command before to the command after. You can avoid it by quoting your arguments:

```
if /i "100 | say" == "100 | Say" echo yes
```

Comment: Yes but the
    set Line=%Line:~6,-1%
removes that and just keeps it as "Say", no?

Comment: I copy-pasted the code from your question and it seems to work fine here. Nevertheless: get used to quote the arguments with `if` - it avoids a lot of problems. Also use quotes with the `set` command: `set "var=value"` for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put quotation marks just in case:

```
IF /I "%Line%"=="Say" goto DoTheSay
```

Comment: Left side of `==` has literal double quotes, right side has no double quotes. Doubt will ever match. Suggest you double quote right side to become `"Say"`.